# Facebook gives error on opening profile using user id

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

Why "http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=10000373602----"

bring "Sorry, this page isn't available The link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed."

This user has properly logged in and authenticated my app and then my app got its log lived token and saved which shows profile is working. But after that i get many problems with graph API. To check issues i opened above like to see the profile but i get above mentioned sorry message. This is happening to 5 users out of 25 users of my app. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you still query public data about the user with his user id?

Comment: Sorry about my last comment. I don't get public data when i use this: https://graph.facebook.com/100003736025182  or use this
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100003736025182

Comment: Are you sure about the statistics of 5 out of 25 users. Cause this looks like the user either deactivated or deleted his/her account

Comment: i have just confirmed 3 however 5 users reported this problem during the last one month and with every id the problem was exactly same.

Comment: I feel you should launch a bug [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs) also, cause it seems a bigger issue. Also check for errors or alerts on your app, maybe you might have got some error code that would be helpful to solve the issue